# Prevent Bootstrap from affecting a particular div in my html page

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Is there any possibility to prevent Bootstrap from affecting a div and its sub-divs from my HTML page?
When I added Bootstrap, the images under this div have become more pale and got a blue shade I do not want.
Thanks for listenning.

I have not tried something particular other than changing the class of div, but with no wanted changes.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent Bootstrap from affecting a particular div by creating a custom class and applying it to that div. This way, Bootstrap will not apply its styles to that particular div.

For example, let's say you have a div with the class "my-div" that you want to prevent Bootstrap from affecting. You can create a custom class like this:

```
<style>
  .no-bootstrap {
    all: unset !important;
  }
</style>
```

Then, you can apply this class to your div like this:

```
<div class="my-div no-bootstrap">
  ...
</div>
```

By doing this, you are instructing the browser to unset all styles applied to the div, effectively removing any styles applied by Bootstrap. The !important keyword is used to ensure that the custom class overrides any existing Bootstrap styles.